# ember-native-class-codemods TypeError: Cannot read property 'process' of undefined

Tags: javascript, ember.js, jscodeshift

My test app is using ember-cli and ember is 3.28. When I tried to use ember-native-class-codemods to convert my test appli
cation it throws below error,

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'process' of undefined
    at bLZ (C:\Users\AS0002\AppData\Local\Volta\tools\image\packages\ember-native-class-codemod\node_modules\ember-native-class-codemod\node_modules\flow-parser\/flow_parser.js:565:79)
    at C:\Users\AS0002\AppData\Local\Volta\tools\image\packages\ember-native-class-codemod\node_modules\ember-native-class-codemod\node_modules\flow-parser\/flow_parser.js:566:4
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\AS0002\AppData\Local\Volta\tools\image\packages\ember-native-class-codemod\node_modules\ember-native-class-codemod\node_modules\flow-parser\/flow_parser.js:2:2)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1085:14)
    at Module._compile (C:\Users\AS0002\AppData\Local\Volta\tools\image\packages\ember-native-class-codemod\node_modules\ember-native-class-codemod\node_modules\pirates\lib\index.js:136:24)
    at Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1114:10)
    at Object.newLoader [as .js] (C:\Users\AS0002\AppData\Local\Volta\tools\image\packages\ember-native-class-codemod\node_modules\ember-native-class-codemod\node_modules\pirates\lib\index.js:141:7)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:950:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:790:12)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:974:19)
```

It was already reported in github issue but no solutions mentioned
https://github.com/ember-codemods/ember-native-class-codemod/issues/392

I have installed `ember install ember-classic-decorator` and `ember install ember-decorators` and my project is running while running the npx command.
Below is my versions,
ember-cli: 3.28.5
node: 14.19.3
os: win32 x64

Comment: As of now, I did include --no-babel option in codemod-cli project and running.